# Lame not generating wav file on LAMP server while working on WAMP

Tags: lame

I have uploaded lame.exe & lame_enc.dll in root folder of my project. 
For example : `C:\wamp\www\lame\lame.exe & C:\wamp\www\lame\lame_enc.dll`

I use following php code to generate wav file :

```
$tmpname = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);

copy($_FILES["mp3"]["tmp_name"], "{$tmpname}_o.mp3");

exec("lame {$tmpname}_o.mp3 -m m -S -f -b 16 --resample 8 {$tmpname}.mp3 && lame -S --decode {$tmpname}.mp3 {$tmpname}.wav");
```

This code is working in my `localhost/lame/`

But did not work on `http://demo.phxsolution.com/mp3wave/`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You've included the Windows version of LAME in your project, but you're trying to run it on a Linux server. You're going to need to configure LAME on the Linux server itself, either by including it in your project somehow, or (more recommended) installing it separately on the Linux server and calling it (as an external application) from your PHP script.

Comment: Hi, Can u tell me where can i find linux version and how to install it using FTP or by cPanel ?

Comment: That's more of a question for your server's administrator. If you're using cPanel, you're most likely using a shared host. They aren't always big on letting external code run on websites. Contact support to see if they allow it.

Comment: Ok and what about documentation of how to install on linux ?

Comment: Give [this](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Lame_Installation#GNU.2FLinux.2FUnix_instructions) a read, see if it helps.